# "rewrite" structure for subdomain on Nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I want to do a custom `rewrite` for the subdomain on ISPconfig. When I add the code below for this, the subdomain is redirected to the main domain.

**Sample #1:**

```
server {
  ...
     if ($http_host = "panel.example.com") {
         rewrite ^(?!/(_SubDomains/Panel|stats|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /_SubDomains/Panel/$2 last;
         rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2? last;
      }
  ...
 }
```

If I do as in example two, Nginx server does not work.

**Sample #2:**

```
server {
...
     if ($http_host = "panel.example.com") {
         rewrite ^(?!/(_SubDomains/Panel|stats|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /_SubDomains/Panel/$2 last;
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2? last;
         }
     }
...
}
```

I was using in Apache server like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Without rewrite link: `https://panel.example.com/index.php?cmd=abc&scd=xyz`

With Rewrite: `https://panel.example.com/abc?scd=xyz`

How can I use it on Nginx PHP-FPM server like I use it on Apache server in subdomain?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to explain better. @MrWhite

Comment: you want server_name domain.bla.tld instead of if, if is bad for nginx